# RUNAS: Error 5 "Access denied" thrown when executing "runas"-command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

when executing the command `runas /user:*admin-user* "test.bat"` from my windows account (no admin) in a command prompt, I recieve the error:

`Error 5 "Access denied"`.

Does anyone no why this error is produced? I already tried the commands

`net stop seclogon`

and

`sc sdset seclogon D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPDTLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWDTLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPDTLOCRRC;;;AU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)`

to fix this as recommended on the Microsoft Support page but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a password for that user? Error 5 is an access denied message, so clearly the command you're running is insufficient to gain the access privileges you were hoping for.

Comment: Yes, the command prompt opens as expected when using the "runas"-command and after I type in the password for my administrator account it is accepted and my batch-file is tried to execute. Then I get the error.